# Using partial wildcard in Glob

Tags: python, glob

I haven't been able to find a use case of this, but basically I was trying to utilize glob for a part of the filename.

```
file_name_date = time.strftime("%m%d%y")
h_server = time.strftime("%-I%p")    
filename = 'PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.GGV1051.' + file_name_date + '.' + h_server + '.txt'
```

This works fine in my code, however now the GGV1051 is changing with each file, so I was hoping to do something like

```
filename = glob('PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.' + * + '.' + file_name_date + '.' + h_server + '.txt'
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed. I didn't see a clear path with either [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) or [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), but I'm not well versed in those libraries.

My thought is to create a string like this:

```
filename = str('PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.?.' + file_name_date + '.' + h_server + '.txt')
```

which would yield:

```
PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.?.062917.12P.txt
```

and then do something like

```
glob(filename):
```

But that doesn't work as intended.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: use `os.listfiles` to get all files in your directory and you use a for loop to check if ***PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*** is in the filename.

Comment: That will end up taking a while as the folder is full and all filenames will have PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY, that's the only thing dropped in folder. My hope was to utilize a wild-card for the GGVXXX part, because each day will have a unique date and time, so if I'm searching for PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*.062917.11A.txt it's only ever going to pull down one file, same the next day when run as PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*.063017.11A.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glob` to match pathnames like `/home/juser/something/*.txt` for all text files within `/home/juser directory`. You can use it to match simple filenames like `*.txt` for all text files in the current working directory.

`fnmatch.fnmatch` and `fnmatch.filter` are used for filenmaes. The former, tests if a filename matches a pattern and returns `True` for matched names, otherwise `False` for unmatched names. The latter, returns the matched filenames according to the giving glob pattern.

All your filenames begin with PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY. and end with .txt suffix, then to match all files that begin with PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY. and end with .txt irrespective of what's in the middle:

```
glob.glob("PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*.txt")
```

This glob matches any filename that starts with PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY. and ends with .txt suffix, it doesn't matter what comes after PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY. the `*` wildcard character matches any arbitrary character. `?` matches only one arbitrary character. Note, This matches filenames in the working directory of your script. If you need to match names in a different directory, pass `"/path/to/my/PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*.txt"` to `glob`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to cut down on the time, because this search will get expensive soon, since I know that the combination of date and time, which I have, will always be unique, is there a way to encapsulate that. I see what you're saying about the * inbetween Intraday and txt, but that returns thousands of files. If I can simply pass todays date and the time function, that will return only one file, the GVXXXX is irrelevant, it's pushed from our mainframe, all I want to do is just exclude it in finding the file.

Comment: @Benloper I hope I'm getting you right this time. In your question you tried to match  `'PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.?.' + file_name_date + '.' + h_server` because you use `?` instead of `*` and because the date and time are unique then  `'PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*.' + file_name_date + '.' + h_server`  should do the job. Here's the trick, change the unknown part to `*` and write the rest of filename that you know (the known part of the filename). Did this help?

Comment: Yes, I think I have it now. I basically did what you said, but I did put it in string, and then pass the string to glob, which worked. filename = str('PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*.' + file_name_date + '.' + h_server + '.txt')
filenames = glob.glob(filename)

Comment: @Benloper glad to hear that :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, the asterisk symbol `*` should also be a string.

```
import glob
all_files = [] 
for file in glob.glob('PRD.FRB.D01.INTRADAY.*.' + file_name_date + '.' + h_server + '.txt''):
    all_files.append(file)
```